# Combining the results of two different cypher queries in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a family tree graph. There are a few people I'm interested in, and seeing who their immediate family are. I have a nice query that will return the siblings of a person of interest:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[]-(parent:Person)-[]->(parents_kids:Person)
WHERE p.`person_of_interest` = 'y'
RETURN p, parent, parents_kids
;
```

I also can return the children of a person of interest:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[]->(children:Person)
WHERE p.`person_of_interest` = 'y'
RETURN p, children
;
```

These queries work fine separately, but how do I return the results together?

The issue is that sometimes, people of interest don't have kids in the database. On the other hand, sometimes people of interest don't have their parents in the database. So I can't write one query to match both cases.

I'm wanting to get a simple table out...I'm thinking something like this where there are `NULL` values where appropriate:

```
| person_of_interest | silblings | children |
|--------------------|-----------|----------|
|                    |           |          |
|                    |           |          |
```

If this is unclear, I can of course modify this question with a minimal reproducible example. Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to assume in your first match between p and parent that the direction of the relationship is downward from parent to child? With an undirected relationship, you're matching parent to both p's parent and children (or to whatever else relationships from a Person point to)

Comment: Also, for output, are you wanting a column collecting parents, and a separate column collecting the children? Or do you want a single column containing both parents and all children (if they exist)? Or something else? If you provide your desired query output, it would help us provide a more useful solution.

Comment: #1 Yes I could put that arrow up there to make the direction more clear. In my case it doesn't change anything due to how my graph is set up, but thank you for the observation.

Comment: #2 good call on the desired output. I'll get on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query should return the `Person` of interest, and (possibly empty) collections of his: `parents`, `siblings`, and `children`.

```
MATCH (p:Person {person_of_interest: 'y'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[:HAS_CHILD]-(parent:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (parent:Person)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(sib:Person)
  WHERE sib <> p
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(kid:Person)
RETURN
  p,
  COLLECT(DISTINCT parent) AS parents,
  COLLECT(DISTINCT sib) AS siblings,
  COLLECT(kid) AS children;
```

The query assumes that the `HAS_CHILD` relationship type is used to denote the parent-to-child relationship.

To speed up the finding of the person of interest, you should create an [index](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-schema-index) or [unique constraint](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-constraints) on `:Person(person_of_interest)`.

Comment: Your last edit really made it all come together. The output is now a list of key, pairs. This is fantastic. I'll use this as the base for a lot of my work from now on. Thank you so much!!